# Phalcon php installation error: download failed

Tags: homebrew

I'm trying to download and install phalconphp using Homebrew on my Mac (Sierra). I’m getting this error:

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
Error: Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable/portable-ruby-2.3.3.leopard_64.bottle.1.tar.gz
```

Things I did:

- Reinstalled Homebrew
- `brew update`
- Tried to download `portable-ruby-2.3.3.leopard_64.bottle.1.tar.gz` (result: This site can’t be reached)

Any idea what is the problem? :/

Comment: Can’t you run `curl -LI https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable/portable-ruby-2.3.3.leopard_64.bottle.1.tar.gz`? I get a 200, not a 404.

Comment: @bfontaine still getting 404
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 29 Oct 2017 11:20:49 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: Can you open it in your browser? http://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable/

Comment: @bfontaine yes i can. There is some files.

Comment: Do you see the `portable-ruby-2.3.3.leopard_64.bottle.1.tar.gz` one?

Comment: @bfontaine it works now. i think problem was with homebrew sever. now it works. :) thanks for help :)